# Scrolling Scroll view behind view

Tags: scroll

i have View with alpha .5  with equal height and width to screen . I have to implement scroll view behind that  view, Could anyone tell me how to implement it ?

Comment: scroll view should work fine.

Comment: Please post any attempts you have made to integrate scroll view to gain feedback. The current question is not a valid question under the current stack recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

As of Swift 5:

You can set the ScrollView as a child of the View in the Storyboard editor. Simply drag the ScrollView inside the View. The tree should look like the following:

```
View
  ScrollView
    < ... >
```

The ScrollView should be scrollable.